# To which Stack Exchange site does this question belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Question Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475949/when-should-i-use-textcontent-innerhtml-and-innertext

This is a question on HTML and JavaScript. I do realize that the question doesn't contain any code and asks about a property or attribute. The question has been put on hold as not programming related.

Please suggest a Stack Exchange site that would be appropriate for this kind of question.

Comment: At a quick glance, the question is too broad but is a programming question. Part of the problem is that it isn't "...a specific programming problem...". If you were to explain what *you know them to mean/do* and possibly links to docs where you showed effort in understanding then it would be appropriate. Something like this, I would close as "too broad" without showing any effort other than saying, "All three seem to do the same thing". And I'm not sure why you edited to remove the link to your original question because it seems to be relevant.

Comment: I think the question was closed for the wrong reason. I agree with @codeMagic, it was too broad, and that would be a valid reason for closing it. But your question was definitely about programming.  Unfortunately, some of the users with moderation privileges are quicker to vote than they are to examine that which they are voting on.